# How to build event recommender based only on events' descriptions

Tags: classification, svm, python, recommender-system, topic-models

I built a simple app that grabs events using eventbrite and meetup.com APIs and displays it based on your zip code. Now I'm trying to build a simple event recommender that will use events that you marked as interested/not-interested as a training set. Two main questions here:

- What would be the best way to extract features from events' descriptions?
- How big should be the training set?

I used LDA to model topics based on descriptions so for every event there's a feature matrix which represents topics. Then I tried different classifiers linear SVC, KNearestNeighbors, RandomForest but nothing gives good results (not better than random classification). Is LDA a good way to extract features for this situation? Also the training set is just 356 events with 254 out of them marked negatively. Am I doing everything completely wrong? ;)